# Complex memory management issue in C++

Tags: c++, performance, memory-management, containers

#### I need to conceive an efficient particle system in C++, that would handle lots of particles with forces applying to them.

*Here are the requirements:*

- Efficiently create and destoy lots of particles and forces, dynamically.
- Particles store x/y/z positions and speeds, mass, air friction and maybe some additional other properties.
- Particles don't need to be extended (no inheritance graph).
- Forces are polymorphic objects which mainly have a getAcceleration() virtual method.
- Several or no forces can be applied to one particle.
- One force only applies to one particle, and when this particle dies the force has no more meaning and should be deleted.
- A force can involve several particles (including the one it is applied to).
- When one particle dies (is removed), forces involving it may or may not die too, according on the type of the force.
- The engine has to be able to iterate through all particles and all forces at each frame in order to perform the calculations

I'd like to have a nice and clear object model so that it could be maintained and extended well.

#### Additional informations:

Forces could be displayed (drawing little arrows on the screen), so it would probably be nice to model them as real objects.
Particles would usually be created by a "physical object", that creates one or more particles (applying forces on them) and can remove them whenever it wants to (if the physical object becomes immobile, if it leaves the screen, or whatever reason).
(Note that forces would not only be created by "physical objects", though.)

So far I've come to a draft where I try to minimize dynamic allocations, because they're slow, and particles would be likely to appear and die in great numbers every second.

```c
#include <vector>

typedef double nb_t;

struct Particle {
    nb_t x, y;
    nb_t sx, sy;
    nb_t mass;
    nb_t air_friction;
};

class Force {
public:
    virtual nb_t get_x_component() = 0;
    virtual nb_t get_y_component() = 0;
    virtual ~Force() = 0;
};

class Engine {
protected:
    std::vector<Particle> particles;
    std::vector<Force*> forces;
public:
    void refresh();
    void addParticle(Particle& p);
    void removeParticle(int index);
    // ...
};
```

But then, how is the owner of the particle (or more exactly its creator, the physical object) supposed to keep track of its particles, and be able to order their removal?
I think smart pointers could be useful, but I'm not sure reference counting would be appropriate, as a particle that dies should be instantly removed from memory to let others be allocated.

Also, isn't there an STL container that would store my objects in an array (like vectors do), without regard to the order (unordered_vector?) but that would put the last element instead of the element we try to remove, so that element removal does not entail translating all the following elements?

#### What do you think would be best? What would be a good compromise, trying to keep efficiency, clarity and scalability?

Comment: What you describe as an `unordered_vector` seems to be a **circular buffer** and I believe [Boost has that](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/circular_buffer/doc/circular_buffer.html).

Comment: Sounds to me like a case where you should start from the spec level of what you're doing, implement a working version that meets the spec, refine the spec and implementation when you realize you got it wrong, and *then* worry about performance.  (It's easy to write fast but incorrect and/or useless code.  Or: "doesn't matter how fast it is if it isn't what you actually want")

Comment: I'm with @HostileFork. It sounds like it is way too early for you to think about "complex memory management". Think through your functional requirements, get a simple implementation working (e.g., generate a new vector<Particle> in every frame), figure out which object needs to know about which particles, etc.

Then, try optimizing. FWIW, it is quite likely that most time will be spent evaluating forces (esp. if you are using an O(N^2) algorithm).

Comment: I agree with both of you in that optimization should be considered _after_ design.  
As for me, I have already programmed a couple of physics-based systems for games. It came out they were pretty inefficient but also very cumbersome.  
I was also very interested in knowing how to solve this kind of problems efficiently (as a personal interest).

Answer (score 1):

In regards to your creation and deletion of objects you want to never want to call new or delete, or try to minimize this. This minimization can be accomplished by making a memory pool and using that for object allocation.

It looks like you want to pools of objects one for the particles and one for the forces.

http://pastie.org/private/ivmu9ogvrf5vurjrwuqmka

That code is a very simple and not very robust memory pool, but could give you some better ideas on how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Here are minor observations regarding architecture, i'll let other address the issue of memory management itself

The virtual call needs to process as much particles as possible at once, so you might want to reconsider your single `getAcceleration()` interface by something more dense like `computeAccelerationsForParticles( std::vector<int>& particleIndices)` or `computeAccelerationsForParticles( ParticleGroup& particleGroup)`. In this way the overhead of the virtual call is spread from once-per-particle to once-per-force-group

This architecture would imply that you need to keep track of particles by force groups. if you want to display particle specific data (like forces) you might add a particle debug structure that is only updated when is not null, so you don't get that overhead when doing 'windowless' simulation